# How can I divide two numbers in ML defined as a datatype?

Tags: sml, ml

I'm trying to write a recursive function in SML that receives two natural numbers n1,n2 and returns the result of n1 div n2

The datatype natural is defined as follows:

```
datatype natural = zero | Succ of natural
```

I want to write it in terms of the new datatype , or in other words, not by converting them to their regular form and converting back the result.

Any ideas how division is done in this definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could start by defining subtraction:

```
exception Negative

fun sub (a, zero) = a
  | sub (zero, b) = raise Negative
  | sub (Succ a, Succ b) = sub (a, b)
```

From here, it should be pretty easy to simply count how many times you can subtract `n2` from `n1` without going negative. In particular, this equation should help:

```
n1 div n2 = 1 + (n1 - n2) div n2
```

I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: Thanks alot! I was to able to write the rest with your help!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Sam Westrick's definition, "number of times you can subtract `n2` from `n1` without going negative", you could also do integer division with addition and greater-than using the definition, "number of times you can add `n2` to itself before it is greater than `n1`."

```
datatype nat = Z | S of nat

fun gt (S x, S y) = gt (x, y)
  | gt (S _, Z) = true
  | gt (Z, _) = false

fun add (x, Z) = x
  | add (x, S y) = add (S x, y)

fun divide (_, Z) = raise Domain
  | divide (x, y) = (* ... *)
```

Addition might seem like a conceptually simpler thing than subtraction. But greater-than is a more expensive operator than determining when a number is negative, since the case is incurred by induction, so Sam's suggestion would be more efficient.

You might test your solution with the following tests:

```
fun int2nat 0 = Z
  | int2nat n = S (int2nat (n-1))

fun nat2int Z = 0
  | nat2int (S n) = 1 + nat2int n

fun range (x, y) f = List.tabulate (y - x + 1, fn i => f (i + x))

fun divide_test () =
    let fun showFailure (x, y, expected, actual) =
            Int.toString x ^ " div " ^ Int.toString y ^ " = " ^
            Int.toString expected ^ ", but divide returns " ^
            Int.toString actual
    in List.mapPartial (Option.map showFailure) (
         List.concat (
           range (0, 100) (fn x =>
             range (1, 100) (fn y =>
               let val expected = x div y
                   val actual = nat2int (divide (int2nat x, int2nat y))
               in if expected <> actual
                  then SOME (x, y, expected, actual)
                  else NONE
               end))))
    end
```